# IOS distributed application crashes

Tags: ios

I have develop an application with a little framework. We are at the final version of the application and the previous versions was distributed for beta test. After test my new version with provisioning profile on my iPad and iPhone I proceed to the distribution to beta testers with ad-hoc distribution. The problem is when I download the application as a beta tester the application crashes every time at the same action, when I test the same application installing it from Xcode it don't.

I have look the crash log and found the line where it does. It's a recently changed part of my framework. The framework is a target of my main project, like a static library but it should be compiled every time I clear all and compile the main project. It's possible that, even if when I compile to install directly on my iPad it do it well, when I compile for distribution it don't recompile my framework? What could be happening here? Any idea of how to proceed?

EDIT: I add part of the crash log, the line where it cranes is the line that calls a new part of my framework

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSYS)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   APPPOS                      0x00098058 0x8000 + 589912
1   APPPOS                      0x00099434 0x8000 + 594996
2   APPPOS                      0x0009909c 0x8000 + 594076
3   APPPOS                      0x000b75d4 0x8000 + 718292
4   APPPOS                      0x00096e8e 0x8000 + 585358
5   APPPOS                      0x0008009e -[TTServerSingleton initServer] (TTServerSingleton.m:62)
6   APPPOS                      0x0008885c -[TTServerControllPreferencesViewController serverEnabledValueChanged:] (TTServerControllPreferencesViewController.m:61)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x36aa03f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
8   UIKit                           0x36ddafa8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
9   UIKit                           0x36ddaf64 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
```

Comment: Not 100% but is there a build flag for that framework and it just isn't complied on a release build?

Comment: Check the build settings and configuration. Look out for your framework. Im not 100% sure but sounds like your issue...

Comment: The target build must fail if the used library is not built in the first place. What is the crash exactly ?

Comment: I add the crash log to the post. I don't see any flag that can made the compiler to don't recompile the framework

Comment: It could be an issue around compiler optimization. When you run it from Xcode is it executing with build configuration "Debug"? if so try switching it to "Release" and see if you able to reproduce the crash.

Comment: I think it's a good idea! How I should do that?

Comment: You need to edit the scheme for your target. In the top (scheme) pull down menu that contains all your project's targets, ensure that the target you are interested in has a "tick" beside it then select "Edit scheme..." option below the target name. This opens a new window, in the left menu select "Run <target name>.app" and in the "info" tab, you should see the "Build Configuration" drop down, select "Release". Now when you run the target from Xcode it should use the same optimization as occurs when you Archive the target to produce an adhoc build. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: That way it works fine... I edit schemes and make it release mode. After I compiled it and it works well. I really don't understand what happens. Something it's done wrong when I archive...

Comment: I tried to archive the app in debug mode changing the certificates of debug mode but it didn't work too... Anyone with another idea?